# How much data does a string data type take up?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Very simple question, how much data (bytes) do strings take up? Do they take up 1 byte per character?

I tried searching it up, but ws schools doesn't say...

I want to know this to reduce bandwidth in my web app.

Also, for anyone that knows, does socket.io automatically json stringify when using `socket.emit()`;?

Comment: As a side thought: If you're worried about bandwidth it might be worth looking into a leaner JSON alternative like [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org).

Comment: I use socket.io, and I don't think its flexible enough to use other stringifying methods other than the one it is already using (JSON)

Comment: I'm sure you could find ways to make it work. A simple search pulls up this [socket.io parser based on MessagePack](https://github.com/darrachequesne/socket.io-msgpack-parser).

Comment: It depends on the encoding, ebcdic take 4 bits for character. UTF-8 take 8 bits per character (one byte). Some encodings use both 8 bits and 16 bits for representing characters...

Comment: ori, are you saying that the data used has a direct relation to the length of the string?

Comment: Yes, you can look at strings as if they were arrays of characters. The memory one is taking has direct relation to its length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is a character array. So, it will take up roughly `sizeof(char) * noOfCharacters` ignoring other fields in String class for now. Character can be of 1 byte or 2 bytes depending upon the system, the type of chars being represented- unicode etc.
However, from your question, you are more interested in data being transported over the network. Note that data is always exchanged in bytes (`byte[]`) and thus string will be converted into byte[] representation first and then ported over.
To limit the bandwidth usage, you can enable compression, choose interoperable serialisation technique(protobuf, smile, fastinfoset etc)